# Calender and SimpleDateFormat outputting the wrong date

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

Whenever i do this code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("D:M:Y");

System.out.println("Date Launched: " + "[" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + "]");
```

It prints out

```
 Date Launched: [285:10:2015]
```

How can i get it so it prints out the actual date like `[12/10/2015]`?

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This problem has been covered hundreds of times already. Rather than intuiting the parsing pattern codes, study the [class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). And copy working code provided in the many examples found here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");//d small
```

[SimpleDateFormat doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are setting wrong format.

Instead of:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("D:M:Y");
```

Use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Where:

```
y   Year            Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year       Year    2009; 09
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year     Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
```

You can read more about `SimpleDateFormat` in oracle's documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

symbol 'd' means day in month

symbol 'D' means day in year

Answer (score 0):

use dd/MM/yyyy instead of D:M:Y so your code looks like

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

System.out.println("Date Launched: " + "[" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + "]");
```

because D gives Day in year bt u want day in month

M gives Month in year

Y gives Year